# make implementation dependency available in another submodule

Tags: gradle

I have submodule `rest` that defines couple of dependencies with `implementation`. And I have another module `app` that uses `implementation project(":rest")`.

However the dependencies of the `rest` declared with `implementation` are not available for `app`. I know `implementation` does that by design, but how to make them available without using original `compile` configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I need to use plugin `java-library` and use `api` configuration for that dependency.